# can't connect to docker container localhost connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, docker

very new to docker. following this tutorial: https://medium.com/thecodefountain/develop-a-spring-boot-and-mysql-application-and-run-in-docker-end-to-end-15b7cdf3a2ba

I followed all the instructions (my application is called `accessing-data-mysql`) but I think I should have two containers running: one for mysql and one for the application. But when running `docker container ls` I only see the mysql container listed. Below I am creating a docker container for my application's image and linking it to the running instance of mysql container.

```
PS C:\projects\project1> docker run -d -p 8089:8089 --name accessing-data-mysql --link mysql-standalone:mysql accessing-data-mysql
82f499c6897d1f6bd2eeaabe4aa25ae786508146929a7039785e4ca37d691435
PS C:\projects\project1> docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
62029a53b9d4        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql-standalone
PS C:\projects\project1> docker run -d -p 8089:8089 --name accessing-data-mysql --link mysql-standalone:mysql accessing-data-mysql
```

my docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:12
ADD target/user-mysql.jar user-mysql.jar
EXPOSE 8089
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "user-mysql.jar"]
```

when connecting via browser to localhost:8089, I get connection refused error. Not even sure if the service is running.

below is the result of running docker logs:

```
PS C:\projects\project1> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                 NAMES
82f499c6897d        accessing-data-mysql   "java -jar accessing…"   50 minutes ago      Exited (0) 50 minutes ago                         accessing-data-mysql
62029a53b9d4        mysql                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour            3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql-standalone
PS C:\projects\project1> docker logs accessing-data-mysql
Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
PS C:\projects\project1>
```

EDIT:
When I run locally directly from Idea, I see the error: No such host is known (mysql-standalone), which is the mysql url I configured to connect to docker mysql. As soon as I change the mysql url to localhost:3306, it can connect. Does this mean that somehow the my-sql docker instance is not accepting connections?

Comment: Can you check all the containers with docker ps -a, then check your app container with docker logs yourcontainername to see why it failed to launch?

Comment: Also, --link- should not be used anymore, you should create a docker network. I'll explain more in an answer once we can get more details on the container failure :)

Comment: @Faeeria i've added the logs

Comment: When you launch the app locally, do you get more logs from the app ?

Comment: @Faeeria I responded with latest edit.

Comment: When you start the app with the localhost host (the error you get here is normal btw), do you have an initialization line ? Or only `Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your container is not up and running. You need to see the container as up when you do `docker ps`. You should see something like this:

```
~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
62029a53b9d4        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql-standalone
XXXXXXXXXXXX        openjdk             "java"                   XX minutes ago      Up xx minutes       8089/tcp              accessing-data-mysql
```

If you are not able to see the second container, it means it's not running. You will need to find the reason for not running by getting the logs with `docker logs accessing-data-mysql` and see why the second container is not starting.

Also, consider creating a `docker-compose` for both containers and establish a separate network. This is not required, your example can work without this, but it makes the things much easier for management and also for troubleshooting.